# What kinds of sports are suitable/not suitable for Gerd?

Tags: sports

For [gastroesophageal reflux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastroesophageal_reflux_disease)  patient, what kinds of sports are helpful and what are not suitable?

Should swimming be avoided?

How about weight lifting, running, yoga, ...?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: I'm no doctor, but if he didn't tell you now to do anything in particular, than why should we expect any problems? Besides it will mostly depend on the severity of the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, part of the answer depends on how/why you've got GERD. If yours is like mine [A], you need to do things that do not compress the abdomen (road biking [B] and sit-ups) as well as keep ones' head raised above one's body (so no hanging upside down). None of the nearby gyms [C] have pools, so I can't test swimming.

Notes:
A - I shouldn't eat chocolate, alcohol or fatty foods, as those irritate the situation.
B - With the ram's horns handlbars. Ones where I sit upright (such as hybrid, mountain or commuter bikes are fine).
C - In the chain I'm a member of.